# Php Arrays / Sort by Date

Tags: php, arrays

How would you go about implementing an array design and function to achieve the following table in php. The data would be drawn from a mysql database but i would like to limit the number of mysql queries required and therefore use a formatted array of some sort.

```
-----------------------------------------
|           | 2009 | 2008 | 2007 | 2006 |
-----------------------------------------
| country a | d d  |      | doc  | doc  |
| country b |      | doc  | doc  |      |
| country c | doc  | d d  |      | doc  |
| country d | doc  |      | d d  |      |
-----------------------------------------
```

Where both d & doc are documents. And any date(y) / country can have many documents.
The resulting table would be an html table.

Comment: are you storing the data as a triplet of (year, country, document) in mysql?

Comment: No, The Query consists of 3 tables via a JOIN, countries (iso,name),documents(id,country_iso,publication_date(datetime)),files(document_id,name)

Could you suggest a mysql query and php function to print this to a table? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using arrays to manipulate or group data if you can help it.  Try to get mySQL to do all the heavy lifting.

For example:

```
...GROUP BY YEAR(item_date)
```

Have a look at the [Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) in mySQL.